# changing font and adding colors to the font using eForm in modx

Tags: html, fonts, colors, modx-evolution

just would like to add that, this is the code for the eForm. Not sure where to use the CSS. Do I need to edit the main css of the page?

how can I change the font on this code & add color to the text, I'm using this to the eForm created in modx

```
<div style="background-color:#CCDFED">
<form method="post" action="[~[*id*]~]">
    <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="registrationForm" />
    <table>


    <tr>
        <td><label for="reasons" style="margin:0.5em">Reason for contacting us:</label></td>
        <td><textarea cols="60" rows="3" name="reasons" eform="Reasons::1"></textarea></td>
    </tr>



    <tr>      
         <td><label for="products" style="margin:0.5em">Which sweets </label>
        <label style="margin:0.5em">do you like:</label>     
         <td>       
            <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="icecream" eform="Sweets::1"/>&#09;Ice Cream <br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="products[]" value="bananasplit"  />&#09;bananasplit<br/>            
        </td>
    </tr>  


    <tr>
        <td><label for="how" style="margin:0.5em">How did you hear about us:</label></td>
        <td>
       <select name="how" style="width:200px" eform="How::1" >
       <option value="web_search">Web search</option>              
       <option value="friends">Friends</option> 
       <option value="word_of_mouth">Word of Mouth</option>     
       </select>
       </td>
    </tr>   
</table>

</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are best off to ask this question in the official modx forums: http://modxcms.com/forums/

but the simple answer is: use CSS.

- remove your inline styles from the chunk & replace with css class or id rules, then you can control the display from your CSS sheet.
- if this is a default chunk with the plugin/extra etc, always work on a copy of it or updates will wipe your customizations away.

Also, Revolution or Evolution & version numbers is helpful to the rest of us.

-sean

Comment: thanks for the reply. not sure where I can find the version numbers but this is what I found under the System Info: rev 6066

Comment: sounds like revolution to me, as fara s I know the chunk system has not changed. My suggestion should still work.